# (Swift) How to make async code, synchronously?

Tags: swift, async-await

I am making an application using Swift.
I want to take data from FireStore, but the problem is that the application goes on to the next job, before finishing retrieving data.
So I tried to use this "DispatchSemaphore" code, but this stops the application from working...
I want to know how to wait the getDocument closure to finish its task, and move to next.

```
func changeTerms(uniqueName: String) {
        print("colRef: \(colRef.document(uniqueName).path)")
        let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
        colRef.document(uniqueName).getDocument { snapShot, err in
            if let err = err {
                self.makeAlerts(title: "Error", message: err.localizedDescription, buttonName: "OK")
            } else {
                if let doc = snapShot, doc.exists {
                    if let data = doc.data() {
                        if let terms = data[K.Fstore.data.attributes] as? [String] {
                            var temp: [String] = []
                            for attIdx in self.rankedAttributes {
                                temp.append(terms[attIdx])
                            }
                            self.attributeTerms = temp
                            print("attributeTerms: \(self.attributeTerms)")
                            self.showTitle()
                            self.showTerm()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            semaphore.signal()
        }
        semaphore.wait()
    }
```

Comment: The  closure could start the next document get before it ends.

Comment: *How to make async code, synchronously?* Don't, please learn how asynchronous data processing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue with Firebase, and I found the solution using `withCheckedContinuation()`. You can learn more about it [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-continuations-to-convert-completion-handlers-into-async-functions).

Your code could be:

```
let temp: [String] = await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        colRef.document(uniqueName).getDocument { snapShot, err in
            if let err = err {
                self.makeAlerts(title: "Error", message: err.localizedDescription, buttonName: "OK")
            } else {
                if let doc = snapShot, doc.exists {
                    if let data = doc.data() {
                        if let terms = data[K.Fstore.data.attributes] as? [String] {
                            var temp: [String] = []
                            for attIdx in self.rankedAttributes {
                                temp.append(terms[attIdx])
                            }
                            self.attributeTerms = temp
                            print("attributeTerms: \(self.attributeTerms)")
                            self.showTitle()
                            self.showTerm()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            continuation.resume(returning: temp)
        }
}
```

The execution will wait for the variable `temp` to get a value, before it moves on.

This is still an asynchronous code, running in the background, but it will run sequentially.